# Jinja2 inline comments

Tags: python, macros, jinja2, comments

How can I put comments inside Jinja2 argument list declaration ?

Everything I have tried gives an error:
**jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char u'#'**

```
{{ Switch('var',
    [('1', 'foo'),    #  comment 1
     ('2', 'bar'),    ## comment 2
     ('3', 'rum'),    {# comment 3 #}
     ]) }}


{% macro Switch(var, caselist) %}
    {% for case, action in caselist%}
        CMP  {{var}} {{case}} 
        JNE  {{LABEL}}
        {{action}}
        JMP  {{LABELF}}
{{LABEL}}:  NOP
    {%- endfor %}
{{LABELF}}: NOP
{%- endmacro -%}
```

In my case Jinja2 is used as macro preprocessor for assembler.

Comment: While you're generating assembly, your question doesn't actually seem to be related to that.  You could be generating HTML or C++ and it wouldn't change your question.

Comment: Useful link: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/

Answer (score 223):

Jinja2 has no support for comments within a `{{ ... }}` statement. You can only use comments *outside* of such statements, and then only with `{# .. #}` or `## comment`.

- `{# .. #}` is only meant for *disabling* part of a template or adding comments *outside* of other Jinja2 syntax. You can't nest these.
- `# statement` is the equivalent of `{% statement %}`, if [line statements are enabled and so configured](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#line-statements).
- `## comment` only works if line statements are enabled, at which point it regarded as a comment.

Generally, outside of Jinja statements, use comments in the target language instead; e.g. `<!-- comment -->` when generating XML, etc.

Comment: external comments looks not such pretty in my case :(

Comment: "`{# .. #}` is only meant for disabling part of a template" – does not match the current documentation, where it is also used as `{# a comment #}`.

Comment: @timss: That sentence should be read *in the context of this question*, where the OP used `{# comment 3 #}` within a block. Yes, `{# ... #}` are used for commenting, including commenting out (disabling) part of a template.

Comment: If to use <!-- comment --> then it will be parsed in webbrowser. Chrome -> Sources; Firefox -> Debugger. Potentially insecure in case comments are well described. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59178354/why-does-django-parse-tags-in-commented-html-code

Comment: @Alexred: yes, that's why they are *outside of Jinja statements*. They are part of the output, which can be any (textual) format.

Answer (score 27):

<strike>*Now Jinja2 has a comment statement*</strike> (This has since been deprecated):

```
{% comment %}

   <html code/>
   {% some other statements %}
   {{ some.values }}

{% endcomment %}
```

Comment: May I use it within a {{ ... }} statement ?

Comment: @kimstik, sorry I dont uderstand your question. But I am edit my answer, plz see it

Comment: I love your approach. Stay curious and motivated. Explore a little deeper

Comment: For some reason, I still don't have {% comment %}, but then I have used: {% if False %} instead, and I guess it is the same idea.

Comment: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'comment'.

Comment: With ansible, I get AnsibleError: template error ... unknown tag comment.

Comment: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#comments doesn't seem to support this comment tag being available.  also, i get the exception as the two prior uh... commentors ;-) when i try to use this tag.

Answer (score 12):

I was trying to add comments to Martijn Pieters.

`{% .. %}` = `{# .. #}`

`{{ .. }}` = `{# .. #}`    (same as above)

Answer (score 1):

```
{#
comment with text and disable JINJA Execution
#}
```