# How can I read comment blocks from a Jinja2 template?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have found that Jinja2 templates have the `.blocks` property, which provides access to named blocks. However, it doesn't provide comment data (understandably).

Is there a programmatic or *reliable* way to retrieve comment content from a Jinja2 template? (Ideally, I'm avoiding writing a regex, as I presume the parsing is built in... I just haven't found it).

**Here is an example:**

Given this Jinja2 template:

```
{#
Comment block content.
#}

{% block main %}
This is the main block. We don't really care about it.
{% endblock %}
```

... I would like to be able to retrieve the following:

> Comment block content.

---

Is there a bulit-in, perhaps undocumented way to get at this content reliably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I browsed through jinja's source code and other articles, and there does not seem to be a way to collect jinja2 comments natively. Per Martijin Peter's answer on [Jinja2 Inline Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562222/jinja2-inline-comments), the `{# #}` syntax *can* be used as inline comments, but they are primarily used for disabling part of the template

> **Answer**
>
> *{# .. #} is only meant for disabling part of a template*
>
> **Comment**
>
> *... Yes, {# ... #} are used for commenting, including commenting out (disabling) part of a template*.

As a work around, you can either use regex (which you've stated you wish to not use) or you can switch to standard HTML comments and use [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4). Using BeautifulSoup does support collecting comments natively with ease

```
template = '''<!--
Comment block content.
-->

{% block main %}
This is the main block. We don't really care about it.
{% endblock %}'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
soup = BeautifulSoup(template, 'html.parser')
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
print(comments)

>>>['\nComment block content.\n']
```