# Why does django parse tags in commented HTML code?

Tags: django

Why does django parse tags in sections of the template that are commented out with HTML comments?

Comment: You comment out with `{# ... #}`, or between `{% comment %}` and `{% endcomment %}`.

Comment: Sure, but why does Django not take the html comments into account?

Comment: into account in what sense? It renders the comments, and does resolution, just like it does with everything else. Note that Django templates do *not* understand HTML. You can render text, email, XML, JSON, etc. with these as well. It is just an engine to render a stream. It has no understanding of the structure of that stream.

Comment: That makes sense...

Comment: Well I often use Haskell's Yesod framework that has "Shakesperean templates". These (to some extent) indeed understand HTML, and thus can say at compile time that a template is invalid, but, to the best of my knowledge, there is no such template engine for Django: https://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is still part of the content you write in the response. It is not said that HTML comment has no meaning. For example one can write JavaScript code that inspects the HTML code, and process these comments, for example as directives how to change the DOM. Parts commented out in HTML (between `<!--` and `-->`) are still part of the DOM, and a parser thus can interprete these.

In order to [comment out parts in the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#comments), such that these are *not* passed to the response, you can use:

```
{# … #}
```

or you can write the content between the [**`{% comment %}`** and **`{% endcomment %}`** template tags [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#comment):

```
{% comment %}
    …
{% endcomment %}
```

Comment: See comment Willem's above "Django templates do not understand HTML" - simple enough. But not convenient in any way.